# Сбросить ползунки в Ion.RangeSlider

Tags: jquery

Стоит слайдер

> http://ionden.com

Как сделать, чтоб при клике на кнопку, слайдер сбрасывался

```
            <div class="title">Этаж, эт.</div>
            <div class="fb-sect">
                <input type="text" name="r-etazh" id="etazh" />
            </div>

<span data-fieldsearch="reset">Сбросить </span>
```

Comment: приложите код слайдера

Comment: или хотябы напишите какой именно вид слайдера вы используете...а то он на сайте не один

Comment: изменил, там любой слайдер